# User created using using System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement unable to access Sharepoint site

Tags: c#, sharepoint, active-directory

Relevant Code: -- This is a work in progress, and I'm still in the discovery stage, so not all exception paths are complete.  No snark about re-throwing exceptions -- I'll get to it.

I also have to say that I have minimal experience with AD.  It's never really come up for me before.

Most of the code came from Microsoft Examples.

```
public static bool AddUser(string firstName, string lastName, string userLogonName,
    string employeeID, string emailAddress, string telephone, string address,
    string Password, DateTime expiry)
{
    PrincipalContext principalContext = GetContext();

    // Check if user object already exists in the store
    if (UserExists(userLogonName))
    {
        throw new Exception(userLogonName + " already exists. Please use a different User Logon Name.");
    }

    // Create the new UserPrincipal object
    UserPrincipal userPrincipal = new UserPrincipal(principalContext);

    if (lastName != null && lastName.Length > 0)
    {
        userPrincipal.Surname = lastName;
    }

    if (firstName != null && firstName.Length > 0)
    {
        userPrincipal.GivenName = firstName;
    }

    if (employeeID != null && employeeID.Length > 0)
    {
        userPrincipal.EmployeeId = employeeID;
    }

    if (emailAddress != null && emailAddress.Length > 0)
    {
        userPrincipal.EmailAddress = emailAddress;
    }

    if (telephone != null && telephone.Length > 0)
    {
        userPrincipal.VoiceTelephoneNumber = telephone;
    }

    if (userLogonName != null && userLogonName.Length > 0)
    {
        userPrincipal.SamAccountName = userLogonName;
    }

    userPrincipal.AccountExpirationDate = expiry;


    userPrincipal.SetPassword(Password);

    userPrincipal.Enabled = true;
    userPrincipal.PasswordNeverExpires = true;

    try
    {
        userPrincipal.Save();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        throw new Exception("Exception saving user object. ", e);
    }
    return true;
}
```

AND

```
public static void AddUserToGroup(string userLogonName, string groupName)
{
    try
    {
        using (PrincipalContext principalContext = GetContext())
        {
            GroupPrincipal group = GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity(principalContext, groupName);
            group.Members.Add(FindUser(userLogonName));
            group.Save();
        }
    }
    catch (System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryServicesCOMException e)
    {
        throw e;
    }
}
```

When I run my test, (add user) and check Active Directory, the user is there.  So far so good.

Then I ran my add to group test, and the user shows as MemberOf  group in AD.  Again, everything is as expected.

Now I navigate to the Sharepoint site and try and login as the newly created user.  I get the "Sorry, this site hasn't been shared with you."

... Interlude: much poking around groups and permissions ensues to no avail ...

Next, I created a user manually in AD, and then ran the Add To Group test.  Everything looks good in AD, and I can successfully login to the Sharepoint site.

So, I suspect that there is something  wrong with the AddUser method, but I can't figure out what.  I see no difference between the user created programatically and the user created manually.

Comment: AD is finicky. I would start by comparing the two accounts' attributes (navigate to the OU the accounts are in, and look at the **Attribute Editor** tab. This tab does not show up if you don't go to the OU the account is in directly and if you don't have Advanced Features turned on). My guess is that the one created with the AD GUI is setting some attribute that your code does not.

Comment: Yeah, that's my suspicion as well.  It's just a matter of figuring out what.

Comment: If you have more than one domain controller, have you waited long enough for replication before testing? (a half hour should be more than enough) Verify that the account is not disabled, that the password is not set to require change on next logon, and that the account expiry date is in the future.

Comment: @GabrielLuci  I think that's the answer.  The account I created yesterday is suddenly working. (Looks like an answer, smells like an answer...)

Comment: Awesome! I'll write up an answer with that and some tips on avoiding replication issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in our comments, just wait longer for your changes to replicate to all the domain controllers before you test.

Depending on how your `GetContext()` method is written, you could even have replication issues creating the account. If it's creating a new `PrincipalContext` object each time, it could theoretically connect to a different DC the the second time, where the new account doesn't exist yet. (although it tries to connect you to the closest one, so it will likely always be the same one)

To avoid any chance of getting a different DC, you can either reuse the same `PrincipalContext` object, or can you read the [`ConnectedServer`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement.principalcontext.connectedserver) property of the `PrincipalContext`, which will tell you which DC it ended up using. You could then use that in later to make sure you're making all your changes on the same DC.

The constructor for `PrincipalContext` will let you pass a specific DC as the domain name if you want to target a specific DC:

```
var context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "dc1.domain.com");
```